# What does the Vedic literature speak about pre-marital sex and sexual abstinence?

Tags: belief, culture, dharma-shastras, sex

I understand that unlike Abrahamic religions, sex is primarily not a taboo in our Sanatana Dharma.

However, I would like to know what is laid out in the scriptures regarding 'pre-marital sex' and also 'sexual abstinence' (preferably for both genders).